# How to create a new text field via a button in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been having this problem forever now. All I want to do is create a button that adds a new (input) text field that is located right beneath the previous one (Like perhaps, a user creating a bullet list with a certain amount of items).

Here is the code I have so far (that pertains to the topic)

```
function addCompanySlotButton(b:MouseEvent){
for(var i:Number = 0;i<slotArray.length;i++){ //slotArray holds the number of text fields (slots) that exist.
    company_slot.name = "slot"+(i); //This is supposed to name the newly-created text field by its index number. (company_slot is just a variable name for the text fields)
    company_slot.y = 30*slotArray.length; //This is supposed to move the newly-created index slot down by 30 * (whatever it's index number is).
    company_slot.x = 75;
    company_container.addChild(company_slot); //company_container is just a display object that shows the text fields/company slots.
}
slotArray.push(company_slot);
trace(slotArray.length); //This number increases every time the button is pressed, so I know for sure that there is more than one text field.
}
```

However, it appears as though all of the text fields are in the same spot, and whenever the button is pressed, ALL of them move instead of just one. I'm pretty new to actionscript (and coding in general), so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to create your TextField object inside the `for` loop : `var company_slot:TextField = new TextField();` ...

Comment: @akmozo Wow... that solved it. Thank you so much!